# IIF()- invalid syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I keep getting this error when trying to run this IIF statement.

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
IIF([Explanation] Like "*No Alternative*" Or Like "*1*" Or Like "*least costly room*" Or Like "*best possible rate*" Or Like "*best rate available*" Or Like "*best available rate*" Or Like "*least expensive*" Or Like "*cheapest hotel room*" Or Like "*lowest price*" Or Like "*cheapest rate*", “No Alternative”, IIF([Explanation] Like "*Required location*" Or Like "*2*", “Required Location”, IIF([Explanation] Like "*Least total cost*" Or Like "*3*" Or Like "*most economical*", “Least Total Cost”, “No Alternative”)))
```

Comment: Here:
Or Like "*most economical*", “Least Total Cost”, “No Alternative”  You have commas there you need to seperate out to more like statements

Comment: "Least Total Cost" is what the output should be if [Explanation] is like the previous string of examples.  "No Alternative" is what the output should be if all the three previous IIF conditions were not present.

Comment: You need to state the field name before every like, not just the first. Adjust that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check for [Explanation]  in each OR  eg:

```
IIF( ([Explanation] Like "*No Alternative*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*1*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*least costly room*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*best possible rate*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*best rate available*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*best available rate*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*least expensive*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*cheapest hotel room*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*lowest price*" 
Or [Explanation] Like "*cheapest rate*"), "No Alternative", 

  IIF( ([Explanation] Like "*Required location*" 
    Or [Explanation] Like "*2*"), "Required Location", 

      IIF( ([Explanation] Like "*Least total cost*" 
        Or [Explanation] Like "*3*" 
        Or [Explanation] Like "*most economical*"), "Least Total Cost",
             "No Alternative")))
```

Comment: That didn't work for me --both adding [Explanation] before each 'Like' and copying the exact statement above.  I still get the same message.

Comment: are you sure you have not some others part of code  that may lead to some problems on IFF  ..??  anyway add  some () for a better closing  of  each logical condition ..

Comment: also changed with regular double quote  the true literal expressions

Comment: thank you.  I ended up just rewriting it all instead of copying and pasting and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
[Explanation] Like "*No Alternative*" Or Like "*1*"
```

you need

```
[Explanation] Like "*No Alternative*" Or [Explanation] Like "*1*"
```